# Why does a while loop work, but not an if statement in returning my values?

Tags: python-3.x

I am a new python coder and I can't seem to understand why the code below works with a while loop but not an if statement:

**CODE1**

```
def getAltitude():

    altitude_prompt = int(input(("Enter the initial altitude(in meters): "))
    if 1 > altitude_prompt or altitude_prompt > 9999:
        print("Altitude must be present between 1 and 9999, inclusive, please try again")
        getAltitude()
    return (altitude_prompt)
```

**CODE 2**

```
def getAltitude():

    while True:
        altitude_prompt = float(input("Enter the initial altitude(in meters): "))
        if 1 > altitude_prompt or altitude_prompt > 9999:
            print("Altitude must be present between 1 and 9999, inclusive, please try again")
        else:
                break       

    return(altitude_prompt)
```

As you can see, these two codes are very similar except in code 1, if I enter a negative number, the prompt restarts but only saves the negative number. Meaning if I put in -3 at first, -3 is saved. Even if I fix it by putting a positive number, 5, when the function reprompts, the function still returns -3.

The second code, however, works completely fine. If I enter a negative number, -3, it redirects the prompt, until I put a positive number, 5, it saves 5 not -3 like code 1.

I'm just curious to why this happens. Is it because I'm calling the function inside the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return the returning value of the recursive call instead:

```
def getAltitude():
    altitude_prompt = int(input(("Enter the initial altitude(in meters): ")))
    if 1 > altitude_prompt or altitude_prompt > 9999:
        print("Altitude must be present between 1 and 9999, inclusive, please try again")
        altitude_prompt = getAltitude()
    return (altitude_prompt)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! How would I do that?

Comment: Oh yeah, I just noticed. Thanks, but could you explain why it works like that?

Comment: Without assigning the returning value of the recursive call to a variable you're simply discarding it, leaving `altitude_prompt` with its original value first entered by the user.